# Sphinx automodule not willing to import Translation

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a sneaking suspicion that Sphinx doesn't like my class Translation.  When I try to do an automethod:

```
.. automethod:: translations.models.Translation.new
```

I get this warning:

```
/Users/dash/Projects/zamboni/zamboni/docs/topics/translations.rst:39: 
(WARNING/2) autodoc can't import/find method 
'translations.models.Translation.new', it reported error: "cannot import name
Translation", please check your spelling and sys.path
```

The path and whatnot are correct.  I've tried importing Translation directly in conf.py and had similar issues.  I still had issues when I tried something like:

`from translations.models import Translation as t`

It was able to import, but an import within Translation eventually caused Sphinx to return the same error.

The documentation in question is here:

[Zamboni Documentation](http://github.com/jbalogh/zamboni/tree/master/docs)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Zamboni source, perhaps you should be doing:

```
.. automethod:: apps.translations.models.Translation.new
```

?